How do I programmatically find out if a windows feature is enabled or not?
I need to be able to determine if a windows feature has been enabled or not.  From digging around and a lot of searching I came up with some code so I can find the windows feature as shown below:
ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_OptionalFeature");
ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
{
    string featureName = (string)objMO.Properties["Caption"].Value;

    if (featureName.ToLower().Contains("websocket"))
    {
        // now where do i get the info on if its enabled??
        Console.WriteLine($"Feature Name: {featureName}");
    }
}

However I have not been able to determine whether or not this feature is enabled or not.  What am I missing?
Thanks!

Related MSDN link - Querying the Status of Optional Features.

Charlieface has an answer using PowerShell.
If you want to use code that's similar to yours, look at the InstallState property on the object. From the Win32_OptionalFeature class documentation:

Properties
The Win32_OptionalFeature class has these properties.
[...]
InstallState
Data type: uint32
Access type: Read-only
Identifies the state of the optional feature. The following states are possible:
Enabled (1)
Disabled (2)
Absent (3)
Unknown (4)
[...]

using ManagementClass objMC = new("Win32_OptionalFeature");
using ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
{
    string featureName = (string)objMO.Properties["Caption"].Value;
 
    if (featureName.ToLower().Contains("websocket"))
    {
        bool isEnabled = objMO.Properties["InstallState"].Value.ToString() == "1";
        Console.WriteLine($"Feature Name: {featureName} (Enabled: {isEnabled})");
    }
    
    objMO.Dispose();
}

You can simplify this by using a ManagementObjectSearcher:
string query = """
    SELECT * 
    FROM Win32_OptionalFeature 
    WHERE Caption LIKE '%websocket%' 
        AND InstallState = 1
    """;
using ManagementObjectSearcher objSearcher = new(query);
using ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objSearcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
{
    // All features in the collection are enabled because the query
    // has a filter on the "InstallState" property.
    string featureName = (string)objMO["Caption"];
    Console.WriteLine($"{featureName} is enabled");
    objMO.Dispose();
}

This approach shouldn't need elevation (at least in my testing it does not).

This works best for my needs... I needed to be able to create a console app to add to an installer routine to check to make sure websocket protocol was enabled or fail the install.  This helps me greatly!

Missing using to dispose all those objects. Also featureName.ToLower().Contains("websocket") would be better as featureName.Contains("websocket", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Good catch on IDisposable. I was really trying not to change OP's code too much which is why I didn't change the string comparison. I would have also recommended checking the "Name" property instead of the "Caption" property since the docs seemed to indicate that would have been more correct.

You can use Powershell for this.
In Powershell this would be simply
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName *websocket*

In C#, you can create a runspace and add that command.
var features = PowerShell.Create()
    .AddCommand("Get-WindowsOptionalFeature")
    .AddParameter("Online")
    .AddParameter("FeatureName", featureWildcard)
    .Invoke();

Then you can look at the State property to see if it's enabled.
Note that this needs elevation.

Thank you for the feedback.  It did not quite meet my needs but... will pass this info on to my team.
